# How to list supported wifi frequencies on windows?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have a Realtek device that is currently doesn't have Linux driver, and it is a a/c type WiFi adapter but cannot detect any 5GHz networks available.

In Linux we can check the supported wifi frequency by wlan device with this command:

```
 sudo iwlist wlp3s0 freq
```

And we can get a list like (this is just an example, not the card currently I am investigating - this one is from ASUS Vivobook X442UR, I think this one is an Atheros):

```
wlp3s0    17 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.805 GHz (Channel 161)
```

So now I know that my wireless device is supporting channel 1 to 13 in 2GHz and only support channels 149, 153, 157 and 161 in 5GHz band. 
This means I cannot set the router to auto select channel in 5GHz band, because if it works in unsupported channels e.g. 5G channel 34 or 165, then this ASUS vivobook will not see the 5G networks.)

Now, the other card from Realtek is already working in Windows 10, but I haven't succeeded installing driver for it in Ubuntu 18.04, so I cannot use the above method to find out the same information.

How do I get the same information from within Windows 10?

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem. You want to check the supported wifi frequency from your realtek card though Windows **OR** you want to figure out why your card cannot detect 5Ghz networks?

Comment: I want to check the supported wifi frequency from your realtek card though Windows

Comment: @Dapid Candra, add the model number of the card please. It looks to me like it's one of the cards that has the extended 5.8ghz channels available, but I have never seen one that's limited to only use those channels.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart The above _sample_ information took from ASUS Vivobook X442UR with `Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)`. While the one I am investigating is Realtek 8811au.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a list of what your device supports, that's a list of what channels your device is seeing as active right now. (I.e. other clients or AP's are on those channels).

The channels supported is defined by the wireless protocol your card supports, in your case it appears to be a b/g card, as it's only seeing 2.4Ghz (unless there's simply no 5Ghz devices in use near by).

Each channel specifies a frequency range, and you can see from the following links which ranges overlap, and which are completely isolated from each other:

[Channels and Frequencies at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Channels_and_frequencies) (Only explains 2.4Ghz),
[Wikipedia's list of channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) (goes into more detail on 5Ghz too).

So, if you have a b or g card, it only supports the 2.4ghz range, n and higher cards support 5Ghz as well, and the channels that provides.

---

Now that's explained, on windows you can do the same command as above (in a command prompt window):

`netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid | findstr /I /R "^ssid | channel | signal"`

This will list the SSID's your card see's right now, along with the channel and signal strength.

To find what channels your card supports however, is still defined by the hardware of the card. Which channel your wifi connects on is decided solely by the access point, not your PC. (Unless running a hotspot but that's an entirely different subject).

Comment: The user claims that he has a Realtek WiFi adapter a/c card.

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira maybe he does - "it appears to be a b/g card, as it's only seeing 2.4Ghz (unless there's simply no 5Ghz devices in use near by)." -- If there's nothing on the 5Ghz spectrum, you won't see anything on the 5Ghz spectrum.

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira and they also claim they are running this command on linux, on their card, while claiming there is no linux driver, for their card.... so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: my mistake... I apologize for the confusion. I will edit my question. Please review it again. Thanks.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I run the command on Ubuntu not on that card, it is just for example. That example can show that there are wifi adapter out there that only support some channels. I want to know if there is same thing in Windows to see supported channels.

Comment: A card which doesn't support all the channels of it's spec isn't a proper card, and I doubt either linux or windows would show you which channels they do support, other than via a custom driver.

Answer (score 0):

Major wifi chipsets usually could operate WHOLE frequency range of given wifi standard: 802.11b/g use 2412-2484Mhz (1-14ch), 802.11a use 4900-6100Mhz (1-200ch), 802.11ad use 58320-64800Mhz (1-4ch), but only some frequencies are allowed in your country (google for "regulatory domain"). Drivers of specific wifi chpiset/adapter should recognize/ask_you in what country you are reside, and limit used channels accordingly. Using unallowed channels in your country is ileggal.

Comment: I usually believe so. But, after I found out about ASUS Vivobook that doesn't work in channel 34 and 165, I start to think otherwise. It's annoying, really, I thought it was defective, any other device can detect the 5G networks, but this ASUS laptop cannot. The first thing comes to mind is that it is broken. But it's not, unfortunately, but I have to set the router manually to work on specific channel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a easier way, but a GUI way, is right click the bottom left of screen over the windows logo, left click device manager, find network adapters and expand view, right click on the one that says wireless, open properties, then you can select and copy the name text for your Wireless network adapter and search for the specs on the internet to see what it supports a/b/g/n 2.4 and or 5ghz...

Comment: That is not easy at all. Searching Internet for supported channel? They don't mention that in their product brief of users manual.

Comment: I'm suggesting a Graphical User Interface way of finding the device driver name then going to the manufactures website to look at the specifications for said device. To make sure it supports 5ghz.