# How to list in Windows which WIFI networks support 2.5G, 5G or both?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

According to [How to list supported wifi frequencies on windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1323493/how-to-list-supported-wifi-frequencies-on-windows) in Linux it's as simple as typing:

```
 sudo iwlist wlp3s0 freq
```

Which outputs something like:

```
wlp3s0    4 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.805 GHz (Channel 161)
```

Whereas in Windows one can type:

```
 netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

(no need for `| findstr /I /R "^ssid | channel | signal"`)

Which outputs something like:

```
SSID 1 : Foo
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : 09:17:e3:91:13:d3
         Signal             : 85%
         Radio type         : 802.11ac
         Channel            : 8
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54

SSID 2 : Bar
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : ed:8f:a2:76:7a:27
         Signal             : 75%
         Radio type         : 802.11ac
         Channel            : 40
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
```

My question is how to get something like:

```
SSID 1 : Foo
    Frequency type          : 2.4G
SSID 2 : Bar
    Frequency type            : 5G
```

?

Comment: Im pretty sure theres nothing built into windows for this, look at WifiInfoView nice little tool.

Comment: It worked! But how does it know? Does it use pull data that is usually hidden?

Comment: It would be in the background somewhere, it may be there, theres alot of better powershell users on here then me but ive never seen it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no other answer came through, I guess the only way is what [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1529427/how-to-list-in-windows-which-wifi-networks-support-2-5g-5g-or-both#comment2319431_1529427) suggested: use the freeware [WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html).